# Using Json.load Changes The Order Of My Config File

Tags: python, json, config

I have been trying to find a solution to this issue and I have not been able to. I have created a UI which runs using a **.config** file. My code retrieves all the necessary information without issues and everything runs smoothly. Currently using this method to read the file since this is what works best for my occasion:

```
    with open(config_file_path_name, 'r') as i:
        self.contents_dict = json.load(i)
```

My problem is the following, I not only use the UI to look through the file and get info but also to adjust values and then write them back to the file at the end. I would have no problem if I never looked into the .config file again but I most definitely have to whenever I would like to add a new field in there (my UI automatically generates any new fields according to the file). Due to this process, I have formatted the **.config** file manually to have things in a specific order so I can easily find my way around when adding things (and to make it look more organized). Problem is when the file goes through the `json.load`, since dictionaries don't need to have a specific order, the file comes out completely rearranged. Not sure why it was designed this way but I cannot find a way to keep the original order of the file.

**Example:**

Let's say the file is set up manually like this:

```
    {
      'C' : '3',
      'A' : '1',
      'B' : '2', 
    }
```

The function `json.load` would immediately change it to something different like this as it reads it:

```
    {
      'B' : '2',
      'C' : '3',
      'A' : '1', 
    }
```

Taking a look here I saw people talking about the `OrderedDict` function but that does not work for me since I want the order I set up before, not the one created by this function. At first I thought it was related to previously using `ast.literal_eval` due to the way the file was formatted but after spending some time changing some things and switching to `json.load` I realized that was not the issue. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: The keys in a JSON object aren't ordered. Any given serialization has a necessarily fixed order, but nothing guarantees that will be preserved through deserialization and serialization.

Comment: That is quite unfortunate though, I get it it still works but I just do not understand why it was made to change the order however it wants. Unless I ask it to, I do not see why they would make this 'order change' a default. Sorry if this is unreasonable, this is my first time using a .config file for my code. Hard to believe there is no solution to this issue though. Thank you for your time!

Comment: It's because not all languages support maintaining the order. (Objects are typically decoded as some form of hash table, where the position of the key depends on the hash table, not the order of the key/value pairs in the object.)

Comment: You should be able to use the `object_pairs_hook` argument to `json.load` to construct the value you want, as it will receive a list of tuples, rather than a `dict`, as its argument.

Comment: I am trying the following according to your explanation here:
`self.contents_dict = json.load(i, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)` 
Currently getting an error though.

Comment: Should we guess what error you are getting, or...?

Comment: My apologies,

Expected type 'Optional[(List[Tuple[Any, Any]]) -> Any]', got 'Type[OrderedDict]' instead

This is the error I am getting when putting the 'object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict' inside of the json.load

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve the issue!

Utilizing the `object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict` does work when opening the file but for some reason it throws a sleeper error when fully written like above. Instead I had to do `from collections import OrderedDict` which then allows me to do `object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict`. My PyCharm still throws the **Optional[(List[Tuple[Any, Any]]) -> Any]', got 'Type[OrderedDict]** highlight but when I run the code it does what it should.

Thank you for your time!